# Unable to store Hive Metastore server and hive shell

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-zookeeper

I updated hive-site.xml with all of the required properties, but I am not able to understand from where this error is occurring. How do I connect metastore to hive shell and to start hive? Before updating meta-store properties hive shell is working properly. 
Can anyone solve this error?

> [hadoop@hduser conf]$ hive --service metastore
>       Starting Hive Metastore Server
>       17/01/02 18:01:01 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist
>       org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:109)
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:91)
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:83)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>       Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create
>   ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:109)
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:91)
>         at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:83)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5968)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5909)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

hive-site.xml:

```
 <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive</value>
    <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scr$
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>
    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/${user.name}_resources</value>
    <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
  </property> 
<property>
    <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
    <value>733</value>
    <description>The permission for the user specific scratch directories that get created.</description>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hive</value>
    <description>
    Local or HDFS directory where Hive keeps table contents.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
  <description>Port number of HiveServer2 Thrift interface.
  Can be overridden by setting $HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
    Use false if a production metastore server is used.
    </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoStartMechanism</name>
    <value>SchemaTable</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://192.168.122.1:9083</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: value of `hive.metastore.uris` isn't : `thrift://localhost:9083` ?

Comment: you can either give localhost or ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

it seems like port 9083 is busy or your metastore is not running as service try some another port